How do whitelist any domain (for 3DS Authorisation)
Background:
I'm working on building a Payment Adapter/sevice for B2B Commerce. But I've come across an issue with implementing 3D Secure 2. This is where the payment provider says that to authorise the card, the transaction needs to be authenticated via 3D Secure directly with the customers bank. This means you need to redirect the customer to their bank to authenticate themselves (eg tapping in some numbers just sent to them via text from their bank). BUT to redirect to the bank, you need to whitelist the domain in Salesforce, which is impossible because there is no way to know what domain you are going to be given by the payment provider (there are 350 banks in the UK alone).
The Question:
Is there a way to switch off or change the security in a Salesforce Digital Community to allow you to perform an HTTP Post to any domain without whitelisting it?
The only way I can think to bypass the restriction is to do it is to redirect to another  site, which we can whitelist, and then get that site to redirect to the customer's bank. But it's a bit crazy.


3DS2 loads the bank authorization via iFrame. iFrame requires a CSP-whitelisted domain. Choose the lesser of two evils: 1) Dynamically update the whitelist via API or 2) Have the iFrame post to your own endpoint that will act as a proxy.

yup that's all I could come up with too... bit rubbish
